# Responding to Node client as soon as Redis key is available

Tags: node.js, redis

On Node, I'm trying to send a response to the client as soon as a bit of data is available and to timeout and return a 404 if the data doesn't become available within the allotted period. The data comes in through another client request that can happen before or after the request that's waiting for the data.

My current attempt is to use Redis and do a RPUSH when the data comes in and do a BLPOP to wait for the data. It's not behaving as I would expect.

Using redis ~0.10.1, my code looks something like this:

Waiting side:

```
redisClient.blpop(key, 10, function (err, value) {
    if (!err && value) {
        res.send(value);
    } else {
        res.send(404);
    }
});
```

Setting side:

```
redisClient.rpush(key, 'something');
redisClient.expire(key, 30);

res.end();
```

My expectation is for the BLPOP callback to be called as soon as the RPUSH call is made. However, the BLPOP times out and I can only read the key on a subsequent request + call to BLPOP.

The first part of my question is about aligning my expectations with the actual expected behaviour of RPUSH/BLPOP on Node.

The second part of my question: I don't really have to use Redis. I'm just looking for *any* way to respond back to the client when an "event occurs" (in the most abstract sense). I'm open to suggestions for alternatives.

Comment: Are you using the same redisClient instance/connection in both the waiting side and the setting side?

Comment: @mscdex Yes, I think I am. This is a single web.js file running on Heroku/Foreman.

Comment: That's probably why you're seeing that behavior then. The redis protocol is generally synchronous, so the node client queues up requests and executes them in series. Try using different redis connections and you should get the expected results.

Comment: Also, if this is just within the same process, you could just create your own EventEmitter instance and signal events. That way you don't have to "leave" the process just to loop right back.

Comment: @mscdex I thought about using EventEmitter, but then I'd have to come up with a solution for when I need to support a Node cluster.

Comment: @mscdex Thank you sir. Your suggestion about using multiple connections worked. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it and close this question?

Comment: redis has a publish/subscribe machanicsm, where you can publish that a key is now availble (from the background worker), use the subscriber (on the client-call side/your frontend) to get the event which gets the value from the key and sends it down to the client. Since HTTP connections close after sometime, you could use longpolling (but would fail in certain circumstances) or use a stateful connection like WebSockets

Comment: @japrescott Pubsub probably won't work in my case because the subscription may be made too late, after the event has been published. I need a mechanism where a subscriber can pick up and event after-the-fact. RPUSH/BLPOP gets closest to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis protocol is generally synchronous, so the redis node client queues up requests and executes them in series. Try using different redis connections and you should get the expected results.